# how to make .animateContentSize() modifier work in both ways?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I've got a composabe and I use `.animateContentSize()` in it's modifier, but it only works when the content size of the composable gets bigger and there is no any animation when the size gets smaller. Is there a way to make it work in decreasing size just like in increasing?

Comment: Please, provide a minimum reproducible sample code.

Comment: Sir it works both ways, so the problem is clearly tied to the specifics of your implementation. We'll need a minimal reproducible example

Comment: I have the exact same issue, ever find anything?