# Modifier.animateContentSize does not animate shrinking of content

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-animation

*This question describes the same problem as explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72063030/8649828), however since it did not provide any code I am opening a new one.*

Using `Modifier.animateContentSize()`, I am able to animate the *expansion* of the content inside the card, however, as opposed to what as far as I know should be happening, I am unable to animate the *reduction* of the content.

Whenever I click the button after it has grown, instead of playing a shrinking animation, it just snaps back to its original size immediately, without any kind of transition.

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun TheThing() {
    var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
    Surface(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
    ) {
        Column {
            Card(
                onClick = { expanded = !expanded },
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(16.dp)
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .animateContentSize()
            ) {
                Text("Clickable", style = MaterialTheme.typography.displayMedium)

                if (expanded) {
                    Text("More text here... ")
                    Text("More text here... ")
                    Text("More text here... ")
                    Text("More text here... ")
                    Text("More text here... ")
                    Text("More text here... ")
                    Text("More text here... ")
                    Text("More text here... ")
                    Text("More text here... ")
                    Text("More text here... ")
                    Text("More text here... ")
                    Text("More text here... ")
                    Text("More text here... ")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: animateContentSize() will not animate how the text disappears

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti what should I use instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you use `AnimatedVisibility` and `animateContentSize` combined.

1. Remove `animateContentSize` from `Card`.
2. Apply `AnimatedVisibility` and `animateContentSize` to expandable content:

```
AnimatedVisibility(visible = expanded) {
    Column(modifier = Modifier.animateContentSize()) {
        Text("More text here... ")
        Text("More text here... ")
        Text("More text here... ")
        Text("More text here... ")
        Text("More text here... ")
        Text("More text here... ")
        Text("More text here... ")
        Text("More text here... ")
        Text("More text here... ")
        Text("More text here... ")
        Text("More text here... ")
        Text("More text here... ")
        Text("More text here... ")
    }
}
```

Full code:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun TheThing() {
    var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
    Surface(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
    ) {
        Column {
            Card(
                onClick = { expanded = !expanded },
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(16.dp)
                    .fillMaxWidth()
            ) {
                Text("Clickable", style = MaterialTheme.typography.displayMedium)

                AnimatedVisibility(visible = expanded) {
                    Column(modifier = Modifier.animateContentSize()) {
                        Text("More text here... ")
                        Text("More text here... ")
                        Text("More text here... ")
                        Text("More text here... ")
                        Text("More text here... ")
                        Text("More text here... ")
                        Text("More text here... ")
                        Text("More text here... ")
                        Text("More text here... ")
                        Text("More text here... ")
                        Text("More text here... ")
                        Text("More text here... ")
                        Text("More text here... ")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I experimented with removing the "modifier = Modifier.animateContentSize()" from the code, and to my surprise, the animation you posted still persists. It's almost as if the animation is not affected by that modifier.

when I attempted to set a custom animation duration using Column(modifier = Modifier.animateContentSize(tween(durationMillis = 6000))), it seems that the specified duration is being ignored. The animation continues to follow its default timing.

Has anyone else encountered this issue or found a way to precisely control the animation behavior and duration in cases like this?

Comment: @Victor, If you would like to set custom duration for expandable you should use `expandVertically` as `enter` and `shrinkVertically` as `exit` for `AnimatedVisibility`, also you can remove `animateContentSize` from `Column`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `AnimatedVisibility` for the content that is inside the if statement. Whats happening here is that your `if (expanded)` statement is running immediately, so it makes your content disappear instantly, then the size changes do animate, but the content is already gone from the composition - making it look like the text is not animating away.

In the below example I'm customizing `AnimatedVisibility` to have a slower speed so you can see the actual animation happening. If you put a border around it you'll see the size animates too:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
@Composable
fun TheThing() {
    var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
    Surface(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),

        ) {
        Column {
            Card(
                onClick = { expanded = !expanded },
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(16.dp)
                    .fillMaxWidth()
            ) {
                Column {
                    Text("Clickable")
                    AnimatedVisibility(
                        expanded, exit = fadeOut(animationSpec = tween(1000)) +
                                shrinkVertically(animationSpec = tween(1000))
                    ) {
                        Column {
                            Text("More text here... ")
                            Text("More text here... ")
                            Text("More text here... ")
                            Text("More text here... ")
                            Text("More text here... ")
                            Text("More text here... ")
                            Text("More text here... ")
                            Text("More text here... ")
                            Text("More text here... ")
                            Text("More text here... ")
                            Text("More text here... ")
                            Text("More text here... ")
                            Text("More text here... ")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: « then the size changes do animate, but the content is already gone from the composition - making it look like the text is not animating away. »  

The problem is that the size change does not animate. That only animates when content is added - the growing animation is there, the shrinking is not.